# how to show toolbox in visual studio for xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm want to learn xamarin native application development but i did not find toolbox to just drag and drop the items is there is any toolbox available in visual studio.

Comment: Just click on `View > Toolbox` or press `Ctrl+Alt+X`

Answer (score 0):

The **[Toolbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/toolbox?view=vs-2019)** window displays controls that you can add to Visual Studio projects.

To open **Toolbox**, choose **View > Toolbox** from the menu bar, or press **Ctrl+Alt+X**.

[image]